# Excel - Is this possible? How to use multiple lookups with index and ranges

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, formulas

I have (2) charts. Listing a range of numbers titles Quantity and Frequency.

I will have (2) user inputted fields in other sheets, but for now I'm just using the placeholder for this example.

So user will input a number for (QTY), and a number for (Frequency) and I need to return the value in the frequency chart.

I've used the index function before, but referencing a second value with a second chart is confusing me.

So essentially I'm trying to figure out how to do: If cell value (QTY) falls in range of chart 1 (Quantity) return the value of the (Price) chart based off frequency.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
=INDEX(C:N,MATCH(D15,A:A),MATCH(E15,C2:N2,0))
```

Comment: And that worked! I think I was over taking it WAY too much. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user3200761 Please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.